# How to Delete Every Row&Columns Which Contains Negative Value

Tags: r, loops

I have dataframe called `lexico` which has a dimension of 11293x512.

I'd like to purge every row and column if any element in that column or row holds negative value.

How could I do this?

Following is my code that I tried but it takes too long time to run since it has nested loop structure.

(I was about to first get every column number that holds neg value in it)

```
colneg <- c()

for(i in 1:11293){
  for(j in 1:512){
    if(as.numeric(as.character(lexico[1283,2]))< 0)
      colneg <- c(colneg, j)
  }
}
```

It would be appreciate for your harsh advice for this novice.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
# create an index of columns with negative values
col_index <- !colSums(d < 0)

# create an index of rows with negative values
row_index <- !rowSums(d < 0)

# subset the dataframe with the two indexes
d2 <- d[row_index, col_index]
```

What this does:

- `colSums(d < 0)` gives a numeric vector of the number of negative values in the columns.
- By negating it with `!` you create a logical vector where for the columns with no negative values get a `TRUE` value.
- It works the same for rows.
- Subsetting the dataframe with the `row_index` and the `col_index` gives you a dataframe where the rows as wel as the columns where the negative values appeared are removed.

---

Reproducible example data:

```
set.seed(171228)
d <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e4, mean = 3), ncol = 20))
```

Comment: you mean d the dataframe in this case lexico?

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha yes

Comment: it looks like you don't creat an index with negative, but positive I guess

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha it creates indexes of which columns/rows to keep; added an explanation now

Comment: I don't know why, but for the both cases of column&row, it returns all NA for col_index typing in console

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha What did you type? Did you try the example I provided?

Comment: I typed:

col_index <- !colSums(lexico < 0) ; returns There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

row_index <- !rowSums(lexico_mat < 0); no error
 
lexico <- lexico[row_index, col_index]; Error in `[.data.frame`(lexico, row_index, col_index) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha you use `lexico` for the columns and `lexico_mat` for the rows, maybe that's the problem? If not, please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) in your question

Comment: the problem is simple. "lexico < 0 " this operation keep returns NA

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha Maybe your data is not numeric?

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha It might indeed be a simple problem, but unless you don't include an example that reproduces this problem the only thing I can do is guessing what might be the problem (as I did in my previous comment).

Comment: How to check whether it's numeric or not? in csv, they look just number.

Comment: ID                     Feature1 Feature2        ...       
1063350.669 935856 37038720 0 30800 0 0 0 0
1063369 0 40320 0 0 0 0 0 0
1063387 0 0 0 0 0 0 8400 0
1063400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1063412.837 -61920 222240 -52800 0 0 0 0 0
1063429.279 1845600 552000 0 0 0 0 0 0
... this is how it looks like in part

Comment: @Coincidence_Alpha It is better (and easier) to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) in the question. To check whether columns are numeric or not, you can use `str(lexico)` or `sapply(lexico, class)`